# How to use innerRef in ReactStrap ? #TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap, reactstrap, react-state

I want to fetch form data from innerRef in Reactstrap. But I am getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

> Code

```
            <FormGroup>
          <Label htmlFor="username"> Username</Label>
          <Input
            innerRef={(input) => (this.username.value = input)}
            type="text"
            name="username"
            id="username"
          />
        </FormGroup>
```

[ErrorScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhRyQ.png)

Comment: The problem you have there is `this` is not defined, so that to set `username.value` fails. Most probably the reason is that you have stateless functional component. Try to convert it to class component. To help you more please post more code of your component

Comment: how to use Inner Ref in functional Components ?

Comment: inside of functional components better to use useState - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html But I think the problem in your case that the component inside of which you have the error should become class in order to have `this` assignable

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this;
For stateless function component:

```
const Header = () => {
  let username: any;
  let password: any;
  let checkbox: any;

  const handleLogin = (event: any) => {
    console.log(
      "Username" +
        username?.value +
        "Password" +
        password?.value +
        "Checkbox" +
        checkbox?.value
    );
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="username">Username</Label>
        <Input
          type="text"
          id="username"
          name="username"
          innerRef={(x) => (username = x)}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup>
        <Label htmlFor="password">Password</Label>
        <Input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          name="password"
          innerRef={(x) => (password = x)}
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <FormGroup check>
        <Label>Remember</Label>
        <Input type="checkbox" name="remember" innerRef={(x) => (checkbox = x)} />
      </FormGroup>
      <Button className="bg-primary" type="submit" name="submit">
        Login
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
```